# Olympiad question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

> Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers such that $ab + 1$ divides $a^{2} + b^{2}$. Show that
>   $$
> \frac {a^{2} + b^{2}}{ab + 1}
> $$
>   is the square of an integer.

It's Olympiad question, any help?